# Apply an SQL script to PostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

In a README file of a repo, it was written to UPDATE DATABASE DETAILS from a root of a project by a command `sudo -u postgres psql -f name.sql` (in linux).
but I am a Windows user and completely new to PostgresSQL, 
and I couldn't find a way to do so in Windows.

I have already installed PostgreSQL and pgAdmin4 on my end.

It would be a real help if you guys can help me in this matter. I am stuck on this matter for 2 days and couldn't find a way.

Comment: `psql -f name.sql` should do it on Windows

Comment: it is showing psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"

Comment: Then you probably need to specify `-U postgres` and provide the correct password for the superuser.

Comment: thanks that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Open `cmd.exe` and run the command from `psql` on.

If `psql` is not on your `PATH`, specify its absolute path.

To connect as a database user whose name is different from your operating system user, use the `-U` option. In your case, you should add `-U postgres`.

Comment: it is showing psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"

Comment: yeah now i got it.